# How to disable activities about people starring my repo on github home page

Tags: github

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPWHL.png)
I don't want to know if someone starred my repo, how can I disable it.

I want to keep it clean for browsing activities by others (like if someone I am following publish a new repo) not by me.